# Strcat cell array and array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cells, cell-array

I have a cell array with strings and a numeric array in Matlab. I want every entry of the cell array to be concatenated with the number from the corresponding position of the array. I think that it can be easily solved using `cellfun`, but I failed to get it to work.

To clarify, here is an example:

```
c = {'121' '324' '456' '453' '321'};
array = 1:5
```

I would like to get:

```
c = {'1121' '2324' '3456' '4453' '5321'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A special version of `sprintf` that outputs directly to a cell array is called `sprintfc`:

```
>> C = sprintfc('%d%d',[array(:) str2double(c(:))]).'
C = 
    '1121'    '2324'    '3456'    '4453'    '5321'
```

It is also a bit different in the way it handles array inputs, by preserving the shape.

Comment: Some [documentation](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function/) on this undocumented function.

Comment: @horchler Thanks.  I usually link to that but this function has gotten [too familiar to me](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2778484+sprintfc). :)

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, you can use `cellfun` – you just need to convert the array to a cell array as well using [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html). Assuming `array` is a vector of integers:

```
c = {'121' '324' '456' '453' '321'};
array = 1:5;
c2 = cellfun(@(c,x)[int2str(x) c],c,num2cell(array),'UniformOutput',false)
```

which returns

```
c2 = 

    '1121'    '2324'    '3456'    '4453'    '5321'
```

In your case, you can also accomplish the same thing just using [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
c2 = mat2cell([int2str(array(:)) cell2mat(c.')],ones(1,length(array))).'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another one-liner, this one without undocumented functions (with thanks to @chappjc for showing me the "format" input to `num2str`):

```
strcat(num2str(array(:),'%-d'),c(:)).'
```

Comment: The inner part could equivalently be `num2cell(int2str(array(:)))`. Despite the title of the question I forgot `strcat`'s cell functionality which simplifies things a lot.

Comment: @horchler Thanks. I just found both approaches have problems with numbers greater than 9. Working on it...

Comment: Solved now. @horchler Thanks again!